# VideoToolbox in iOS 6

Tags: ios, h.264

In iOS 6, `VideoToolbox.framework` has been moved to the public frameworks directory, but I can't add it, it has no header files and there's no documentation. So my question is, is the Video Toolbox framework supposed to be usable in apps yet for hardware decoding H.264 frames?

Thanks.

Comment: Pure guess, it still is only usable by the media player framework and the fact that it was moved to the public frameworks is a faux pas.

Answer (score 2):

It also surfaced in the MacOSX SDK 10.8. Though, on iOS it's still not possible to get a hardware IO-Channel from a user-space process. So things haven't changed, you are still not able to construct a hw h.264 decoder instance...at least not without a jailbreak.
There are reverse engineered headers floating around the internet (check xmbc project), but as I said, just useful with jailbroken devices...